# Is this solution correct? I thought it was meant to be $y = 1/t-c_i,$ if the solution is wrong, what's the correct answer?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The question is solve the following ODE: $t^2y'' =(y')^2 ,\; t>0.$

Here's the solution file:///M:/pc/My%20Documents/Doc3.pdf

This is the solution my lecture provided and I think there's an error somewhere when $c_1$ doesn't equal $0;$ shouldn't it be $y= t^2/2+\ln (1-c_1t) + c_2?$

If the solution is wrong, what's the correct solution? Thanks: spent over 6 hours trying to work it out to come to the conclusion that there's an error.

Comment: We can't access your file. Can you please upload an image inline?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Substitute $$y''=v'$$ then you will get $$\frac{t^2v'(x)}{v(x)}=1$$